# Using Lambda for Sorting

Tags: python, lambda

I have a list which holds data about supermarkets and their forecast figures over a period of 5 months.

I am trying to sort the data so that it is sorted by the supermarket with the highest sales. So the output should be:

```
Morrisons 64000
Tesco 45000
Asda 38000



Supermarkets = [["Asda", 10000, 20000, 15000, 18000, 19500, 38000],
                ["Tesco", 25000, 11000, 14000, 22000, 9000, 45000], 
                ["Morrisons", 19000, 15000, 22000, 21000, 23000, 64000]]
Alldata.sort()

for item in range(len((Supermarkets))):
    highestlist = (Supermarkets[item][0], Supermarkets[item][6])
    highestlist = sorted(highestlist, key=lambda x: x[1])
    print(highestlist)
```

My for loop goes through the entire list (`Alldata`), creates a new lists with just the name of the `Supermarket[item 0]` and then the highest `score[item 6]`.

I am then trying to sort on item 6.

However every time I run the program, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    highestlist = sorted(highestlist, key=lambda x: x[1])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Can somebody please explain why this is happening so I can avoid in the future?

Comment: highestlist is an empty list that I am trying to create within the for loop to display the highest number of sales in order of the supermarket with the highest sale. So it should look something like this: highestlist ["Morrisions", 64000, "Tesco", 45000, "Asda", 38000]

Comment: Clearly at least one `x` is an integer (which makes sense, `highestlist` is actually a tuple of `(string, integer)`, not a list), so `x[1]` can't possibly work. Why don't you `print(highestlist)` *before* trying to sort it, so you know what you're working with?

Comment: If, say, the second value of "Morrisons" were higher than 64000, would it change the sort order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is you build a `(item[0], item[6])` and your loop is looping inside this, which you actually want to loop the outer list instead.

You can simply sort the data on the fly in one line, by using list comprehension to (reduce the list to only item[0], item[6]) and sort altogether:

```
In [11]: Supermarkets
Out[11]: 
[['Asda', 10000, 20000, 15000, 18000, 19500, 38000],
 ['Tesco', 25000, 11000, 14000, 22000, 9000, 45000],
 ['Morrisons', 19000, 15000, 22000, 21000, 23000, 64000]]

# sort from low to high
In [12]: sorted([(s[0], s[6]) for s in Supermarkets], key=lambda x: x[1])
Out[12]: [('Asda', 38000), ('Tesco', 45000), ('Morrisons', 64000)]

# sort from high to low
In [13]: sorted([(s[0], s[6]) for s in Supermarkets], key=lambda x: -x[1])
Out[13]: [('Morrisons', 64000), ('Tesco', 45000), ('Asda', 38000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
Supermarkets = [["Asda", 10000, 20000, 15000, 18000, 19500, 38000], ["Tesco", 25000, 11000, 14000, 22000, 9000, 45000], ["Morrisons", 19000, 15000, 22000, 21000, 23000, 64000]]

highestlist=[]
for item in range(len((Supermarkets))):
    highestlist.append( [Supermarkets [item][0], Supermarkets[item][6]])
highestlist = sorted(highestlist, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(highestlist)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Asda', 38000], ['Tesco', 45000], ['Morrisons', 64000]]
```

**Notes:**

you have created a new tuple and not a list `highestlist = (Supermarkets [item][0], Supermarkets[item][6])`

Even If you turn this `highestlist = (Supermarkets [item][0], Supermarkets[item][6])` to this `highestlist = [Supermarkets [item][0], Supermarkets[item][6]]` you would be creating a single dimensional list.where as you have written a sort function for lists of lists.So appending the values to list to `create a list of lists[LOL]`

Comment: Just tried that but that sorts by the name of the supermarket and not the highest figure of sales.

Comment: @PythonNewBee you want highest figure first and descending order

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, you're trying to make a flat `list` of `["Morrisions", 64000, "Tesco", 45000, "Asda", 38000]`, although you only have two of those at a time. For each two-element flat `list`, your sorting function is trying to take the second element of each item that it gets passed. It can do that with `'Morrisions'`, that second element being `'o'`, but there's no such thing as a second element for an integer like `64000`.

Create this nested `list` as follows:

```
>>> highest_list = [(item[0], item[-1]) for item in Supermarkets]
>>> highest_list
[('Asda', 38000), ('Tesco', 45000), ('Morrisons', 64000)]
```

And then use the sorting function you already have. Remember `reverse=True` to get a descending sort.

```
>>> new_list = sorted(highest_list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
>>> new_list
[('Morrisions', 64000), ('Tesco', 45000), ('Asda', 38000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear, whether you want to sort by the last item in each list or the largest value in each list.

First the more simple case:

In Python you should not use the construct `for i in len(lst)`. It's usually more elegant to simply iterate over the list as is.

Also, it is not necessary to build up the sorted list by hand (and you have already discovered `sorted()` anyway!).

There is a bit of a problem with your logic there, as well. You want to sort and output the list once, but what you really do is sorting and printing it once for every entry in the list (or you would, if the code were actually working ;)

The `lambda` is OK, but I find `itemgetter` more readable - it's a matter of taste.

This is all you really need to do the sorting:

```
from operator import itemgetter

supermarkets = [["Asda", 10000, 20000, 15000, 18000, 19500, 38000], 
                ["Tesco", 25000, 11000, 14000, 22000, 9000, 45000], 
                ["Morrisons", 19000, 15000, 22000, 21000, 23000, 64000]]

sorted_supermarkets = sorted(supermarkets, key=itemgetter(6), reverse=True)
```

And this is how you could output the data:

```
for supermarket in sorted_supermarkets:
    print(supermarket[0], supermarket[6])
```

In case the problem is actually more complicated and you want to sort by the highest value of every supermarket, not just the last value, this is how you could do it:

```
best_months = ((market[0], max(market[1:])) for market in supermarkets)
sorted_supermarkets = sorted(best_months)
for supermarket in sorted_supermarkets:
    print(*supermarket)
```

Or, if you are not interested in the value, but only the order of supermarkets:

```
def key(market):
    return max(market[1:])

sorted_supermarkets = sorted(supermarkets, key=key, reverse=True)
```